# My custom ArrayAdapter only repeats a few items

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, baseadapter

I'm using it for grid view, the count of object displayed is correct and it's returning in log is correct but for example 6 object display and the rest repeat them

1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6,.....

my code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemObject> {

    private static float textViewWidth;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<ItemObject> array, float textViewWidth) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.sample_album_item, array);
        CustomAdapter.textViewWidth = textViewWidth;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        ImageView imgScreenShot;
        TextView txtAlbumName;
        TextView txtAlbumAuthor;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            imgScreenShot = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.screen_shot);
            txtAlbumName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
            txtAlbumAuthor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_author);
        }


        public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<ItemObject> adapter, final ItemObject item, final int position) {
            imgScreenShot.setImageResource(item.getScreenShot());

            String albumName = item.getAlbumName();
            String albumAuthor = item.getAlbumAuthor();

            float musicNameWidthSizeViaParent = widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumName, albumName);
            float musicAuthorWidthSizeViaParent = widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumAuthor, albumAuthor);

            if (musicNameWidthSizeViaParent < 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i < albumName.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumName, albumName.substring(0, i).trim() + "...") < 0) {
                        albumName = albumName.substring(0, i - 1).trim() + "...";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (musicAuthorWidthSizeViaParent < 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i < albumAuthor.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumName, albumAuthor.substring(0, i).trim() + "...") < 0) {
                        albumAuthor = albumAuthor.substring(0, i - 1).trim() + "...";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            txtAlbumName.setText(albumName);
            txtAlbumAuthor.setText(albumAuthor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        ItemObject item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_album_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }

    private static float widthSizeViaParent(TextView text, String newText) {
        float textWidth = text.getPaint().measureText(newText);
        return textViewWidth - (textWidth * G.displayMetrics.density);
    }

}
```

if getView method without this (convertView == null) condition, everything is correct but scrolling is slowly

Comment: So slow scrolling is the issue you're having?

Comment: Use BaseAdapter if you plan to extend it.

Comment: In this case, I searched and understand that smoother scrolling needs this (convertView == null) condition. I don't know what to do about repeat

Comment: @Nanoc, thanks, i try, The problem persists

Comment: Your performance issues are caused by calling inflate() for every row during scroll, dont call inflate.

Comment: for me your code works fine.. check your `array`

Comment: Now I see that my issue is only on api 21 and greater than, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this block of code makes it run slow:

```
public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<ItemObject> adapter, final ItemObject item, final int position) {
            imgScreenShot.setImageResource(item.getScreenShot());

            String albumName = item.getAlbumName();
            String albumAuthor = item.getAlbumAuthor();

            float musicNameWidthSizeViaParent = widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumName, albumName);
            float musicAuthorWidthSizeViaParent = widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumAuthor, albumAuthor);

            if (musicNameWidthSizeViaParent < 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i < albumName.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumName, albumName.substring(0, i).trim() + "...") < 0) {
                        albumName = albumName.substring(0, i - 1).trim() + "...";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (musicAuthorWidthSizeViaParent < 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i < albumAuthor.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (widthSizeViaParent(txtAlbumName, albumAuthor.substring(0, i).trim() + "...") < 0) {
                        albumAuthor = albumAuthor.substring(0, i - 1).trim() + "...";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            txtAlbumName.setText(albumName);
            txtAlbumAuthor.setText(albumAuthor);
        }
```

Two loops runs for every single item. You probably want to have that logic in the models instead. So when rendering the items, albumName and albumAuthor is already set.